# ImageMagick and RMagick Installation Problems

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I've been trying to install ImageMagick using the Mac OS X installer from Ruby Forge and the RMagick code doesnt want to compile, it outputs:

```
Can't install RMagick 2.10.0. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

and

```
have_library: checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... -------------------- no
```

I've tried running the installer again but to no avail. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does the mkmf.log file say?

Answer (score 0):

I've has no problems installing ImageMagick when using MacPorts. The procedure is typically:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
sudo gem install rmagick -- --disable-htmldoc
```

The directive to disable documentation can speed up the installation and can avoid problems with missing fonts when trying to render example images.

MacPorts is located at http://www.macports.org/